# How to stop tcpdump remotely using expect from a new telnet session

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to stop the tcpdump command from running on a remote terminal. If I telnet to the terminal, start tcpdump, and then send a ^c, tcpdump stops with no issues. However if I telnet to the same terminal, start tcpdump, and then exit the telnet session, when I reconnect to the same telnet session I am unable to stop tcpdump via a ^c. When I do this instead of stopping tcpdump it seems that it just quits the telnet session and tcpdump continues to run on the remote terminal. I provided my script below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f

exp_internal 1
set timeout 30

spawn /bin/bash
expect "] "

send "telnet 192.168.62.133 10006\r"
expect "Escape character is '^]'."
send "\r"
expect "# "

set now [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%d_%b_%Y_%H%M%S}]
set command "tcpdump -vv -i trf400 ip proto 89 -s 65535 -w /tmp/test_term420_${now}.pcp "

send "$command\r"
expect "tcpdump: listening on"

# This works correctly. tcpdump quits and I am returned to the expected prompt
send "\x03"
expect "# "



send "$command\r"
expect "tcpdump: listening on"

# Exit telnet session
send -- "\x1d"
expect "telnet> "
send -- "q\r"
expect "] "

# Reconnect to telnet session
send "telnet 192.168.62.133 10006\r"
expect "Escape character is '^]'."
send "\r"

# This does not work as intended. The ^c quits the telnet session instead of stopping tcpdump
send "\x03"

expect "] "
send "ls\r"
expect "] "
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to a subordinate process with Expect, do this:

```
send "\x03"
```

(<kbd>Ctrl+@</kbd>=0, <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>=1, <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd>=2, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>=3, etc.)

The correct handling of the <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> depends on the virtual terminal engine intercepting it and converting a character into a request to send a signal. This *only* happens when the terminal is in cooked mode. You've probably got the terminal cooked — it's the default after all — but if this doesn't work, that's the first thing to check.

Comment: Hi Donal, thank you for your help but your solution didn't work. I edited my question to make it more clear. Sending a ^c does indeed work when tcpdump is started in the same telnet session. However it still doesn't work when I connect to a remote telnet session already running tcpdump. Instead of stopping tcpdump as intended, it seems that sending a ^c quits the telnet session and returns me to my local machine. This confuses me even more. If you could provide any additional insight that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that the `tcpdump` process has fallen to the background after the first telnet session disconnected.

Maybe what you need to do when you connect over your second telnet session is find the process id using `ps` and then signal it via the `kill` command?

Or better yet, launch it in the background in the first place ("&" at the end):

```
tcpdump -vv -i trf400 ip proto 89 -s 65535 -w /tmp/test_term420_${now}.pcp &
```

and the shell will give you the pid of the tcpdump process before it returns the prompt... you can read it via `expect -re` and later on when you re-connect, issue a `kill -HUP <pid>` (or -INT or whatever).

You should get something like the following (using `sleep 5` as command, just as an example):

```
$ sleep 5 &
[1]     29344
$
```

Just my 2c.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion James! Running tcpdump in the background is a nice workaround and is my current solution to the problem. However I'd still like to know why sending ctrl+C doesn't work when telnet disconnects and reconnects. When I telnet manually it is clear that tcpdump is still running in the foreground because I do not receive a prompt and I'm also able to manually ctrl+C out of tcpdump. Something I didn't mention in my post is that I'm actually telneting to a port on a console server to which my terminal is connected via serial cable. Maybe this is somehow causing an issue.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. I hear you... I'm also curious why the different behavior. I'll keep pondering about it, and will come back if I can think of anything.